# Can't add firefox search engines (ubuntu 14.04 & firefox 28)

Tags: firefox, search

From the firefox search engine page (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?atype=4), I get the following error alert message when I click "+ Add to firefox":

> Sorry, you need a Mozilla-based browser (such as Firefox) to install a search plugin.

I've found 2 temporary solutions so far that work fine, but they're workarounds and not exactly an answer to as why this is happening:

**Temp solution #1** is to right-click on the "+ Add to firefox" link, and "save link as" the xml file to /usr/lib/firefox-addons/searchplugins and restart firefox.

**Temp solution #2** use firefox in safe-mode by running ***firefox -safe-mode*** in a terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Th add-on responsible seems to be : Unity Desktop Integration 3.0.2, desactivating it for me resolves the issue.

Since I'm using Ubuntu, I wonder what the desactvation of this plugin will cause however.

Comment: Spot on! I think those plugins are for stuff like showing GMail on a desktop icon. I never use those, so I gladly deactivated.

Comment: This was also raised on the following reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-firefox-extension/+bug/1320474, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1363590